# Arduino ESP32 Import Error No module named serial

Tags: esp32

I googled and couldn't find a solution to my nice problem:
I have Ubuntu and I want to program a ESP32 ...............
I tried a lot of pip commands ... but it didnt work.
You have any idea how to install the correct packages?
Maybe you can tell me what to do. I am really lost.
I tried it last year and also failed.. Now I want to try it another time :)

```
   /.arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/3.0.0/esptool.py", line 38, in <module>
        import serial
    ImportError: No module named serial
```

Answer (score 9):

Open terminal and enter this command `python -m pip install pyserial` it will download `pyserial` for you and you will not receive the above error. The above error is because you don't have `pyserial` installed on the system.

The related documentation for pyserial could be found [here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html)

Comment: python -m pip install pyserial
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip

Comment: @jento you will first need to install pip I considered you have pip installed to install pip use the following command `sudo apt install python3-pip` for python3 or you can use `sudo apt install python-pip` for python 2

Comment: How about doing this but in a virtualenv, so not installing packages system wise?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue compiling the CameraWebServer example. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. The problem occurs during the linking stage when the script invokes python. On my system this runs the system python which is python 2.7.18. I don't think the serial module (supplied by pyserial) is available on Ubuntu 20.04 for python 2.x.

My solution was first to abandon the Arduino IDE and use the arduino-cli to compile the example. I created a virtual python 3 environment, activated it, installed pyserial under the virtual environment and run arduino-cli to make the runtime. The python scripts appear to be compatible with python 3.

Comment: the arduino esp32 python scripts work with python 2 and you can install pyserial into python 2.

Comment: I'm not sure it's available for 2.7.18. In any case, I did not want to install libs into the system python just to make a runtime when I can use a virtual env.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved, Thank you.  I had installed pyserial.  The error surprisingly was related to the incorrect processor speed (!) in the Arduino IDE.  I have no idea why that would influence the serial/pyserial function.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

I think Arduino IDE expects Python2 to be installed. My Version is Arduino-1.8.13
You also need Python2 modules so you need to install pip2

:~/curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
:~/sudo python2 get-pip.py
:~/pip2 install pytools
:~/pip2 install pyserial